# How to treat a string as a variable in java?

Tags: java

Remember playing the game when you indexed each of the words of your name and added it all together to form a secret number? Like `aay` would be `1+1+25=27`

I tried to do the same thing by various methods in java but I failed.Let me share my script first and then tell what all i tried.

```
class test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int c = 3;
            String s = "c";
        ///now this is what all i tried:

        int value1 = (int)(s);
        ///i tried a cast, but that failed.

        String d = "4";
        int value2 = Integer.parseInt(d);
        ///when i try this, it correctly converts the string to an integer.

        Integer.parseInt(s);
        ///but when i try the above, it fails to do the same.
    }
}
```

In this code, I try 2 different methods both of which are working in a similar way that I want to but not exact.

The problem is that it couldn't reorganize that c is a variable that has an integer value.

So, is there any shortcut to do it?
Also, right now the string is only 1 digit long, once the user inputs his or her name, I shall use a for loop to loop all of the letters completely.

If there isn't any shortcut, is the only option left with me is to make an if statement like:

```
if(letter=a;){
    value=1;
}
```

Or something like that?

thanks for helping!

Comment: Use `String.toCharArray()`. `char` itself is a number.

Comment: And you can get the actual number by using `(int)(character - 'a' + 1)`.

Comment: just out of curiosity, is this homework, it is a typical "homework game" to solve.

Comment: no, it isn't a homework, i learn java just for fun as a hobby, so i don't get any homeworks.

Comment: Knowing is half the battle. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Answer (score 4):

You can't convert a String directly into an integer, you need to take one character at a time and subtract the value of the char `'a'` then add 1 :

```
public static void main(String[] a) {
    String s = "test";
    for (char c : s.toLowerCase().toCharArray()){
        System.out.println(charToInt(c));
    }
}
private static int charToInt(char c){
    return c - 'a' + 1;
}
```

Comment: To complete the answer to his question, we sum the result: `int total = 0; for(char c : s.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) total += c - 'a' + 1;`

Answer (score 1):

In Java like most other C-eqsue languages, `char` is a Number type.

> **char:** The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff'
>   (or 65,535 inclusive).

#### Just Alphabetic Characters

So all you need to do is convert each character to its equivilent `char` and you have its ASCII/Unicode value; I won't go into Unicode here, because ASCII maps over Unicode into the correct place.

```
// this will give you a Zero based int of the 
// UPPPERCASE alphabet which starts at `65` and
// ends at `90`. 
// See where the lowercases starts and ends?

char c = "My Name".charAt(0) - 65; 
// c = 'M' in this case which is 77 - 65 = 12
```

#### The [ASCII codes](https://www.asciitable.com/) are easy to translate.

[image: ASCII TABLE]
<sub>(source: [asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif))</sub>

For `UPPERCASE` letters it is just an exercise of looping through all the `char`s of a `String` and getting their code and subtracting `65` to get a `0` based value. It gets a little more complicated to exclude other characters and process `lowercase` as well, but you get the idea from the table.

#### Printable Characters

Notice *"printable"* characters start at `32` and run through `126` which is usually what you just do, is subtract `32` instead of `65` and just convert all *"printable"* characters to a Zero base.

#### Example

The following will print out all the *"printable"* characters.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        for (char i = 32; i <= 126; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(new Character(i));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Solution

Here is a complete solution that will create a secret code, of all the *"printable" characters possible.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        int hash = 0;
        final String s = args[0];
        for (int c = 0; c < s.length(); c++)
        {
            hash = hash + s.charAt(c) - 32;
        }
        System.out.printf("Secret code for %s is %d", s, hash);
    }
}
```

the result for my name is

```
Secret code for Jarrod is 418
```

Comment: C-esque languages = languages that are similar to the language C